# Background of a UIViewController to Grouped table view color

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, background

In a UITableView grouped style, the background of the table view is sort of like a grayish texture color. How can I grab that value such that I can set the entire background of a UIViewController to be that color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are developing for the iPhone and iPod touch, `UIColor` defines a `groupTableViewBackgroundColor` pattern that you can use:

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]];
```

You can also find this color in Interface Builder:

[image]

This won't be available on the iPad, however. You'll have to grab the image yourself and do a `UIColor.colorWithPatternImage:` instead.

Comment: @reising1: This pattern isn't available on iPad.

Comment: What is the background color on an iPad grouped table view?

Comment: @reising1: I don't know, I believe it's just a shade of gray, the one you see on the Settings app maybe.

Comment: how could I get the background color?

Answer (score -2):

...or you could use the pattern color that *groupTableViewBackgroundColor* itself references:

```
[UIColor pinStripeColor]
```

this works equally well on iOS6...

Comment: Is it possible you're using a library, macro, or category that is generating this color? I could not find this color in the iOS documentation.